# PyQt5 unicode translation: pylupdate5 outputs escape sequences

Tags: python, qt, unicode, pyqt, pyqt5

I have an application developed with PyQt5 (Qt5.1.1) on Python 2.7.5. The application makes extensive use of unicode strings enabled using `from __future__ import unicode_literals`. The source code is set `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` and so unicode characters are written as-is in the source (no escaping required).

Translation using `pylupdate5` 'works' in so far as strings are extracted and can be translated using Qt Linguist and re-applied. This works both for strings containing non-ASCII characters and without. However, any strings containing unicode characters end up containing gibberish in the `.ts` file. For example 'Open' followed by an ellipsis is output as:

```
&amp;Open&#xe2;&#x80;&#xa6;
```

The bits after the word are the unicode code units for the ellipsis character (E2 80 A6), although this appears as `â ¦` in Qt Linguist. Translating it (and entering the correct unicode in the translation works fine). Replacing the `â ¦` in the `.ts` file with the corrected unicode stops the resulting translation from working, suggesting `tr` is also seeing the gibberish version.

So what is going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have very little experience with this but looking at the one .ts file I've generated, the first line is <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> and BBEdit confirms it is utf-8 encoded. In which case, a non-Latin-1 character should be displayed properly. In fact I just edited an ellipsis into one of the strings in the .ts file and opened it in Linguist and it displayed correctly. So it could just be a case of file encoding of either the source or the .ts file.