# pylupdate5 returns wrong source strings

Tags: python, utf-8, pyqt, internationalization, translation

I try to run pylupdate5 on a python file with some strings (in french with accents, but all files are in utf8) to translate with `QCoreApplication.translate` but when I generate the `.ts`file I get wrong strings such as :

```
<message>
    <location filename="myfile.py" line="193"/>
    <source>Cr&#xc3;&#xa9;er une trajectoire</source>
    <translation></translation>
</message>
```

instead of the string in the python code "Créer une trajectoire". I think it may be related to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19156794/pyqt5-unicode-translation-pylupdate5-outputs-escape-sequences), but I don't get the space problem, only accents. And when I open the ts file in Qt Linguist, I get the same problem, even if the corresponding code is ok (like in my python IDE).

I run pylupdate5 with :

```
pylupdate5 myfile.py -ts myfile_en.ts
```

Here is my code :

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from PyQt5.QtCore import QCoreApplication

def tr(message):
    return QCoreApplication.translate('myproject', message)

tr("Créer une trajectoire")
```

I am using python 3.8 on macOS with PyQt5.

Comment: Post debugging details including information on the platform, Python distribution, PyQt version, etc. Did you try with the recent PyQt version?

Comment: Done, but internationalization exists since Qt4...

Comment: What distribution? It works fine with brew installations of python3(3.11.4) and pyqt5(5.15.7).

Comment: see my own answer

Answer (score 0):

Found the missing part of my .pro file containing all scripts and UI files to be translated : `CODECFORTR = UTF-8` which tells `pylupdate5` how to decode the original strings (by default it's latin1, found explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28974832/10710693)). I don't know how to use it for single script parsing in command line, but with a .pro file it works well.